# If en arreglo de objetos c++

Tags: c++

Tengo que realizar un programa que cumpla estos requisitos:

Crear un arreglo de 5 posiciones que almacene enteros y realizar:

Mostrar el numero mayor

Mostrar los múltiplos de 5 del arreglo

Mostrar la suma de todos los números del arreglo

Mostrar el numero menor

Crear la clase persona con los atributos (nombre, edad, peso)
Crear un arreglo para almacenar 5 personas.
Mostrar los datos de las 5 personas.
Mostrar las personas menores de edad
Mostrar las personas que pesen menos de 70 kilos

El problema que tengo radica en que no se como llamar al atributo edad para compararlo en un if ya que lo debo hacer con todas las personas del arreglo. Para poder saber cuales son las menores de edad. Agradecería muchisimo su ayuda.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Persona {

private:
string nombre;
int edad;
float peso;


public: 
Persona(){
    this->nombre="";
    this->edad=0;
    this->peso=0;
}

void setPersona(string n,int e,float p){
    this->nombre=n;
    this->edad=e;
    this->peso=p;
}

void getPersona (int i){
   
    cout<<"El  nombre de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"La edad de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->edad<<endl;
    cout<<"El peso de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->peso<<endl;;
}



};

int main (){

    string n;
    int e,personaMenor;
    float p;

    Persona persona[5] = Persona();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona "<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>n; cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese la edad de la persona : "<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>e; cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingrese el peso de la persona : "<<i+1<<endl;
    cin>>p; cout<<endl;
    persona[i].setPersona(n,e,p);
    
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        persona[i].getPersona(i);
    }

   for (int i=4; i>-1; i--){
       if (persona[i]>edad.persona[i-1]){
           personaMenor = persona[i-1];
       }
   }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estimado:

Si su pregunta es como acceder al atributo edad de su clase, la respuesta es que debe cambiar la accesibilidad de los atributos de su clase de private a pulic, mas o menos así:

```
class Persona {
    public://cambio de private a public
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    float peso;


    public: 
    Persona(){
        this->nombre="";
        this->edad=0;
        this->peso=0;
    }

    void setPersona(string n,int e,float p){
        this->nombre=n;
        this->edad=e;
        this->peso=p;
    }

    void getPersona (int i){

        cout<<"El  nombre de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->nombre<<endl;
        cout<<"La edad de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->edad<<endl;
        cout<<"El peso de la persona "<<i+1<<" es: "<<this->peso<<endl;;
    }

};
```

Luego para llamar a los atributos dentro del método principal, debe hacer referencia a cada índice del array de objetos ponerle un punto y luego el nombre del atributo a llamar, más o menos como se muestra a continuación dentro del main()(revise los comentarios dentro del código):

```
int main()
{
    string n;
    int e,personaMenor;
    float p;
    
    
    Persona persona[5];
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        //persona[i]= new Persona(); //lo comente ya que marca error de sintaxis   
        cout<<"Ingrese el nombre de la persona "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>n; cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese la edad de la persona : "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>e; cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese el peso de la persona : "<<i+1<<endl;
        cin>>p; cout<<endl;
        persona[i].setPersona(n,e,p);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        persona[i].getPersona(i);
    }
    //Su enunciado decía que era para las personas menores de edad, la cual depende del pais, en ese caso muestro el nombre de la persona menor de edad, usted puede mostrar los atributos que desee
    cout << "Personas menores de edad:" << endl;
    for (int i=4; i>-1; i--){
        if (persona[i].edad < 18){
        cout << persona[i].nombre << endl;
        //printf(persona[i].nombre);
        }
    }
    //igual que el caso anterior pero muestra el peso
    cout << "Personas menos de 70 kg:" << endl;
    for (int i=4; i>-1; i--){
        if (persona[i].peso < 70){
            cout << persona[i].nombre << endl;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Espero le sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

C++ en un lenguaje orientado a objetos. Este paradigma basa una de sus premisas en dejar cierta información oculta al resto del programa. En este caso el estado de los objetos:

```
class Persona
{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    float peso;    
};
```

Declarar las variables en la parte privada de un `class` hace que estos elementos no puedan ser accedidos libremente por el resto del programa.

Si necesitamos acceder (para leer o modificar) a uno de estos elementos podemos crear las funciones correspondientes:

```
class Persona
{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    float peso;

public:

    int GetEdad() const
    { return edad; }

    // Si no necesitas modificar la edad, basta con eliminar esta función
    // para garantizar que nadie podrá modificar la edad de una persona
    void SetEdad(int edad) 
    { this->edad = edad; }
};
```

Y por qué íbamos a querer mantener estas funciones cuando podemos declarar las variables como públicas?

Bueno, este mecanismo tiene sus ventajas:

- Al estar las variables como privadas, no pueden ser modificadas libremente. Esto reduce el número de errores en el programa
- Es posible meter lógica en las funciones para validar los valores que se van a almacenar en las clases, lo que evita que se introduzcan valores incorrectos o problemáticos
- Al ser las funciones la vía de acceso a las variables, es posible poner puntos de parada en dichas funciones para poder depurar mejor los programas. Si cualquier parte del programa pudiese modificar el estado de esas variables directamente, esta depuración sería más complicada, ya que tendrías que usar breakpoints en memoria, más complejos de gestionar.
- La encapsulación mejora la legibilidad y la seguridad del código
- Otras ventajas ...

Bueno, ya podemos acceder a la edad. ¿Cómo hacemos ahora para comparar la edad de las personas de un array? Facil, veamos el caso de tener que indicar las personas que son menores de edad:

```
cout << "Lista de menores de edad\n";
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (persona[i].GetEdad() < 18) {
       // La función GetNombre no está implementada en este ejemplo
       cout << persona[i].GetNombre() << '\n';
    }
}
```